# Replaced drawable icons not being updated

Tags: android

I have some icon images in my drawable folders that I replaced with updated versions of them. However, when I run the app, the old icons are still showing, and I'm not sure why.

Things I've already tried:

- Uninstalling the app
- Clearing the app's cache
- Invaliding caches / restart
- Clean project
- Rebuild project
- Deleting the `build` folders
- Synced the project

None of these seem to have fixed the issue. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Try this if you haven't already: close the project and reimport it.

Comment: Also right click on drawable folder, click on Show in Explorer and search for subfolders that may keep the old versions.

Comment: Tried both, neither worked. :/

Comment: One more: backup your drawable folder, delete everything inside it. Clean the project and copy back all files/subfolders. Then rebuild

Comment: Have you deleted the app off of the device you are testing on? I think I had something similar and remember removing the app and reinstalling